# Run AWS Lambda code when creating a new AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'd like to run some code using Lambda on the event that I create a new EC2 instance. Looking the blueprint `config-rule-change-triggered` I have the ability to run code depending on various configuration changes, but not when one is created. Is there a way to do what I want? Or have I misunderstood the use case of Lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by inserting code into your EC2 instance launch userdata and have that code explicitly invoke a Lambda function, but that's not the best way to do it.

A better way is to use a combination of CloudTrail and Lambda. If you enable CloudTrail logging (every a/c should have this enabled, all the time, in all regions) then CloudTrail will log to S3 all of the API calls made in your account. You then connect this to Lambda by configuring S3 to publish events to Lambda. Your Lambda function will receive an S3 event, can then retrieve the API logs, find RunInstances API calls, and then do whatever work you need to as a consequence of the new instance being launched.

Some helpful references [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail-example.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/using-cloudtrail.html).

Comment: Thanks, I customized the code from the resrouces you provided to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

We had similar requirements couple of days back(Users were supposed to get emails whenever a new instance gets launched)

1) Go to cloudwatch, then select Rules
2) Select service name (its ec2 for your case) then select "Ec2 instance state-change notification"
3) Then select pending in "Specific state" dropdown
4) Click on Add target option and select your lambda function.

That's it, whenever a new instance gets launched, Cloudwatch will trigger your lambda function.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a notification trigger for instance startup, however what you can do is write a startup script and pass that in via userdata.  That startup script would need to download and install the AWS CLI and then authenticate to SNS and publish a message to a pre-configured topic.  The startup script would authenticate to SNS and whatever other AWS services are needed via your IAM Role, so you would need to give the IAM Role permission to do whatever you want the script to do.  This can be done in the IAM console.

That topic would then have your Lambda function subscribed to it, which would execute.  Similar to the below article (though the author is doing something similar for shutdown, not startup).

http://rogueleaderr.com/post/48795010760/how-to-notifyemail-yourself-when-an-ec2-instance

If you are putting the EC2 instances into an autoscale group, I believe there is a trigger that gets fired when the autoscale group launches a new instance, so you could take advantage of that.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you have CloudTrail enabled, then you can have S3 PutObject/TrailBucket trigger a Lambda function. Lambda function parses the object that is passed to it and if it finds `RunInstances` event, then run your code.

I do the exact same thing to notify certain users when a new instance is launched. With Lambda/Python, it is ~20 lines of code.

Comment: How to create a specific trail for just instance create

Comment: @SoumyajitDutta you can't restrict it to just instance create. All actions are logged and you have to filter only instance create.