# Edit EC2 security group from another AWS account

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I have 2 accounts on AWS. On the first account I have created a permanent EC2 instance with a "dbSG" Security Group (which only allow connections by specific port and IP).

When I create an instance in second account using CloudFormation template it should:

- Add this instance IP to "dbSG" security group and allow connection by specific port.
- Connect to the first instance by this port.

Can I use AssumeRole in UserData when creating the instance in the second account and modify "dbSG" to allow connections from this instance? If yes, how it can be done step by step?

Comment: why the question is tagged with "cloudformation"? would you prefer a solution which uses CloudFormation?

Comment: @SimoneLusenti yes, i'm creating this instances using cloudformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For [EC2-Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

The CLI help for [`ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html) has this example:

> To  add  a  rule that allows inbound HTTP traffic from a  security
>   group in another account
>
> This example enables inbound traffic on TCP port 80 from a source
>   security   group   (otheraccountgroup)   in   a   different AWS 
>   account (123456789012). If the command succeeds, no output is
>   returned.
>
> Command:
>
> aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name
>   MySecurityGroup --protocol tcp --port 80 --source- group
>   otheraccountgroup --group-owner 123456789012

So, provided that you know the Security Group ID of the "appSG", with credentials from the "db" account:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name
dbSG --protocol tcp --port 1234 --source-group
appSG --group-owner XXX-APP-ACCOUNT-ID
```

Via CloudFormation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-sourcesecuritygroupownerid

Unfortunately, this seems not to work with Instances in a VPC, but only EC2-Classic.

---

#### For EC2-VPC: The `user-data` way

In the "db" account, add a Role to your CF template, specifying a Trust Policy that allows such role to be assumed by a specific role in another AWS account:

*(replace XXX-... with your own values)*

```
'RoleForOtherAccount': {
  'Type': 'AWS::IAM::Role',
  'Properties': {
    'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {
      'Version': '2012-10-17',
      'Statement': [{
        'Effect': 'Allow',
        'Principal': {
          'AWS': "arn:aws:iam::XXX-OTHER-AWS-ACCOUNT-ID:role/XXX-ROLE-NAME-GIVEN-TO-APP-INSTANCES"
        },
        'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole']
      }]
    },
    'Path': '/',
    'Policies': [{
      'PolicyName': 'manage-sg',
      'PolicyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [
          {
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Action': [
              'ec2: AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress'
            ],
            'Resource': '*'
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Then, on the "app" instance you can add the following User-data script (via CloudFormation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata)

```
#!/bin/bash

# get current public IP address via EC2 meta-data
MY_IP=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)

# assume the "db" account role and get the credentials
CREDENTIALS_JSON=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn XXX-ARN-OF-ROLE-IN-DB-ACCOUNT --role-session-name "AppSessionForSGIngress" --query '{"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": Credentials.AccessKeyId, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": Credentials.SecretAccessKey, "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": Credentials.SessionToken }')

# here you should find a way to extract AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN from the above $CREDENTIALS_JSON, then export them or pass as values replacing YYY below

# authorize the IP
aws --region XXX-DB-REGION --access-key-id YYY --secret-access-key YYY --session-token YYY ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-XXX --protocol tcp --port 1234 --cidr $MY_IP/32
```

The IAM Role of the "app" instance must allow calls `sts:AssumeRole`.

**Caveat:** if you stop and restart the instance, its public IP will change (unless you've assigned an ElasticIP). Since User-data scripts are executed only during the first Launch, your dbSG wouldn't get updated.

---

#### via Lambda

You could also use a Lambda function triggered by a CloudTrail or Config, altough this is a bit tricky: [Run AWS Lambda code when creating a new AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507438/run-aws-lambda-code-when-creating-a-new-aws-ec2-instance)

This way, you can also track calls to StopInstance and StartInstance and update (revoke/authorize) the dbSG rules in a more robust way.

---

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your situation is:

- Two VPCs, let's call them: VPC-A and VPC-B
- Each VPC is owned by a different AWS account
- Instance-A exists in VPC-A, with Securiy Group `dbSG`
- When launching Instance-B in VPC-B, allow it to access Instance-A

The simplest method to achieve this is via [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html), which permits direct communication between two VPCs in the same region. The VPCs can belong to different AWS accounts, but must have non-overlapping IP address ranges.

The process would be:

- VPC-A invites VPC-B to peer
- VPC-B accepts the invitation
- [Update routing tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/working-with-vpc-peering.html#vpc-peering-routing) in both VPCs to send traffic to each other
- Create a security group in VPC-B, eg `appSG`
- Modify `dbSG` to permit incoming connections from `appSG`
- Associate Instance-B (and any other instances that should comunicate with Instance-A) with the `appSG` security group

**That's it!** Security works the same way between peered VPCs as within a VPC. The only difference is that the instances are in separate VPCs that have been peered together.

See: [Working with VPC Peering Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/working-with-vpc-peering.html)

Comment: Can it be done automatically during the time when instance creates using cloudformation?

Comment: And what if VPC regions is different?

Comment: Unfortunately this scenario can't be deployed with CloudFormation: *With AWS CloudFormation, you can create a peering connection only between VPCs in the same AWS account.*   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html

Comment: If your solution requires CloudFormation, please update your Question to indicate this (aside from just a tag). Also, VPC Peering only works within the same region.